# Can an arbitrary formula in propositional logic be converted to 2CNF, preserving equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose I have an arbitrary formula $\Phi$ in propositional logic. Is there a way to convert $\Phi$ to a 2-CNF formula $\Psi$ such that $\Phi \equiv \Psi$? If not, why not?

Comment: I know that "CNF" stands for "conjunctive normal form", but what does "2-CNF" mean?

Comment: 2-CNF means that each clause contains at most 2 literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Some functions can't get expressed using no more than two variables.  For instance consider the following function

```
 x  y  z  F(x, y, z)
 0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  1
 0  1  0  1
 0  1  1  0
 1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  1
 1  1  0  1
 1  1  1  1
```